# Transaction Recent Blockhash Required - Phantom Wallet Solana

Tags: solana

```
Uncaught (in promise) WalletSignTransactionError: Transaction recentBlockhash required
at PhantomWalletAdapter.signTransaction (adapter.ts:215:1)
at async WalletProvider.tsx:247:1
at async mintNFT (luckoo.tsx:100:1)
```

I got this when im trying to send transaction using solana wallet, what should i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a `recentBlockhash` in your transaction in order for it to be signed.  Most likely, you need to fetch a blockhash and add it before signing the transaction using `getLatestBlockhash`, ie:

```
let blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized')).blockhash;
transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
```

Previously, you would use the similar deprecated function `getRecentBlockhash`:

```
let blockhash = await connection.getRecentBlockhash('finalized').blockhash;
transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
```

Your better bet is to directly use `sendTransaction`, which does all of that work for you.  As you can see in the source code, `sendTransaction` is filling in the recent blockhash if it isn't already present: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/a5b1ebd70ae9753d188fec60e95e252402f3f371/packages/core/base/src/signer.ts#L13

- More info about blockhashes: https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#recent-blockhash
- More info about fetching blockhashes: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getlatestblockhash
- More info about using `sendTransaction`: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter#usage

Comment: `getRecentBlockhash ` is deprecated use `getLatestBlockhash`

Comment: Good spot, thanks!

Comment: Please correct the above to `(await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized')).blockhash;`

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```js
let blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized")).blockhash;
console.log("recentBlockhash: ", blockhash);
```